# Creating a new variable in Rstudio

Tags: r

I currently work in a research lab and recently began looking into the data using Rstudio. I am new to Rstudio and have never coded before. One of the variables is Stim, where the values are different words and I want to create a new variable to categorize the words into three different categories - good, bad, and physical activity. How do I do this?

Comment: Your question is unclear to me. What is the set of words of the variable? What should be the decision rule to reallocate those words into one of the three categories? (Also, your question is about R, not Rstudio. ;))

Answer (score 0):

If you want a dataframe that contains a column `Stim` and a separate column `Category` containing your categorical data:

```
library(dplyr)

# Here is your variable
Stim <- c("Apples","Bananas","Cookies","Deadlifting")

# Creating a dataframe from your variable
df <- as.data.frame(Stim)

# Categorizing your data
# Assuming Apples & Bananas are bad, Cookies are good, and deadlifting is physical activity

df <- df %>%
  mutate(Category =
           (case_when(Stim == "Apples" | Stim == "Bananas" ~ "Bad",
                      Stim == "Cookies" ~ "Good",
                      Stim == "Deadlifting" ~ "Physical Activity")))
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Stim = c("Apples", "Bananas", "Cookies", "Deadlifting"
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is very helpful. However, I am getting an unexpected symbol error on the mutate line of code and not sure what it is

Comment: the error is in the line of code that begins with (case_when(..... it says "Error: unexpected symbol in:

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using? It's hard to diagnose without seeing it.